# Fragment not retaining EditText value after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have already posted this question once and even tried all possible solutions. So please, if are going to downvote, at least provide the correct answer because I have tried out many solutions and nothing is working out.

In my app, I have an EditText inside the fragment which on orientation change, looses its value.One more thing, I am using different layouts for different orientations. Is there any way to retain the fragment data? I am again mentioning "Fragment data".Please find my Fragment code below for further reference.

```
 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    outState.putString("fname",etxt_firstname.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("lname",etxt_lastname.getText().toString());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // retain this fragment
    setRetainInstance(true);
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState!= null)
    {
        etxt_firstname.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("fname"));
        etxt_lastname.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("lname"));
    }

}
```

Inside OnCreateView():

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    shrp_sharedpreferences = myContext.getSharedPreferences("shrp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    View view = null;

    if(!isTablet(myContext))
    {
        if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        {
            view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_landscape, container, false);
        }
        else
        {
             view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        }
    }
    else
    {
        view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }
```

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376824/6834114

Comment: @Omi yes but not working

Comment: you need to call super.onSaveInstanceState(outState); after putting strings

Comment: @AdeelTurk: I have already tried that actually. Still not working.

Comment: @Maddy: I went through that. I need to retain the state for a fragment.

Comment: hey let me get this straight, every thime you rotate the fragment, all you want is to retain the editText value? how is this fragment linked to a activity?

Comment: @MikeM.: inside the onCreate() of the activity:

 blankFragment = new homeFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, blankFragment).
                    addToBackStack("fragBackNew").commit();

Comment: @Remario: Yes exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the fragment itself is retained, its view is destroyed when device is rotated in `onDestroyView()` (You should also clear any references to views there to prevent leaking old orientation).

Trying to restore text in `onActivityCreated()` does nothing because you're referencing views from old orientation, and they aren't used anymore.

When fragment is reattached (in Activity created for new orientation), new View is created in `onCreateView()` - this is where you can use `savedInstanceState` or any fragment fields to restore views to previous state:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // (...) your layout inflation and view binding logic...

    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        etxt_firstname.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("fname"));
        etxt_lastname.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("lname"));
    }
    // return view you inflated
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: @AnimeshJena I've edited my answer